# Unity FPS Sample И версии?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

### FPS Sample

Задействуй читающий, после чудесного релиза FPS Sample я захотел хотя бы воссоздать проект на своем компьютере, ибо проект можно скачать с гит хаб. 
Вроде ничего сложного, но я столкнулся с рядом трудностей что заставали усомнится в своих силах...

---

В общем кратко:

Проблему с HDR я решил просто удалив файлы.

Но потом после прочтения лога в консоле я понял что проблема еще и в версии самой Unity. Обновился до самой последней версии что есть Unity 2018.3.0 beta.

Но меня ждала неудача (будут приложены миниатюры)

/FPSSample-master/Assets/Scenes/testlevel/testlevel_Profiles/Post-process Volume Profile.asset' because it was serialized with a newer version of Unity. (Has a higher SerializedFile version)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и таких сообщений было очень много... 
В общем обращаюсь за советом к бывалым обитателям, прошу не кидаться камнями, ибо я действительно искал информацию в интернете, но это мне не помогло.

- (сайт) https://unity.com/fps-sample
- (github) https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/FPSSample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заходим на github и смотрим описание проекта:

1. Правильно ли вы скачали проект с гитхаба?

> **Getting the project**
>
> To get the project folder you need to clone the
>   project. Note, that
>
> **IMPORTANT**: This project uses Git Large Files Support (LFS).
>   **Downloading a zip file using the green button on Github will not work**.
>   You must clone the project with a version of git that has LFS. You can
>   download Git LFS here: https://git-lfs.github.com/.

2. Вы сказали, что у вас версия 2018.3.0b, какая конкретно бета версия у вас? В любом случае опять смотрим гитхаб:

> Getting the right version of Unity Once you have cloned the
>   repository, you should install the **version of Unity that is listed
>   above in the prerequisites section**. Make sure you include windows
>   standalone support in your installation.

Смотрим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужная версия для проекта 2018.0.3b**6**, последняя доступная в том же UnityHub бета версия - 2018.0.3b**8**, что нас полностью устраивает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте,спасибо за бистрий ответ на этапе установке новой версии я как раз установил 2018.0.3b8. Но вот  Git Large Files Support (LFS) я признаюсь даже не знал толком, просто склонировал репозиторий, и загрузил даний проект зипом. Однозначно спасибо, буду смотреть.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема была в недогруженных файлах ибо не было установлено Git Large Files Support (LFS). Огромное вам спасибо.

Comment: Не за что, дерзайте ;)